# Windows Server 2008 - AD Replication

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, replication

I have 3 Windows Server 2008 servers. Here's the breakdown...

1.) Windows 2008 Standard - Configured as primary AD, DNS and File server
2.) Windows 2008 Enterprise - Secondary DNS  / Lansweeper
3.) Windows 2008 R2 - FTP - Web services

I'm trying to make the 2008 Enterprise box become a redundant AD replication server. However, I can't find any information on where to start.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Run dcpromo on the W2K8 EE server.

Comment: This is correct. Also, I suggest that you start reading up on Windows AD, or hire a qualified consultant to help. If you don't know this sort of basic thing, you shouldn't be administering the servers, in my opinion. My suggestion is to learn first rather than simply not do it, however.